# get baseUrl not using request spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to get the baseUrl without using request, as this will be done by the scheduler, I also don't need any addition to .properties

How can I achieve this from a simple method?

Comment: what is baseUrl?

Comment: baseUrl = schema + domain in the address bar of the browser

Comment: Please provide some code. You probably can specify it in a .properties file and get it in the method. Since baseUrl doesn't change dynamically.